# Cannot set key shortcut on GNAT Studio

Tags: ada, gnat, gnat-gps

I am using the GNAT Studio Community 2020 (20200427) on Windows10.

I want to set a key shortcut for the "Goto declaration or body" action.

I select in the Edit > Preferences... > Key Shortcuts menu, then select "Goto declaration or body",
click on the "Add" button,
type the shortcut (say for example `Ctrl+:`),
then close the Preferences window.

This result is that the key shortcut does not work, although it is added to  `~/.gnatstudio/keys.xml`.

Did I miss something ?
Did someone have the same issue ?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question ... but kudos on using Ada!  I definitely think the world would be a better place if more software was written in Ada, and less in C++ ;)

Comment: I usually just ctrl+left mouse button, which should work by default